# camera capture function is not working for ios

Tags: nativescript

System Version:
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
Xcode 8.3

Plugin Used : nativescript-camera

device used to install app: iPad (version 9.3.5)

Snapshot of code:
capture picture function def

```
public takePicture() {
Camera.requestPermissions();
    Camera.takePicture().
        then((imageAsset) => {
            console.log("Result is an image asset instance");
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = imageAsset;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
        });
    }
```

Tried ways to resolve :
Added NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and NSCameraUsageDescription keys inside .plist file

No error is thrown 
but camera doesnot opens up.

Please suggest

Comment: i am still stuck in it...any suggestions

Comment: package.json:
“dependencies”: {
“@angular/animations”: “~6.0.0”,
“@angular/common”: “~6.0.0”,
“@angular/compiler”: “~6.0.0”,
“@angular/core”: “~6.0.0”,
“@angular/forms”: “~6.0.0”,
“@angular/http”: “~6.0.0”,
“@angular/platform-browser”: “~6.0.0”,
“@angular/platform-browser-dynamic”: “~6.0.0”,
“@angular/router”: “~6.0.0”,
“nativescript-angular”: “~6.0.0”,
“nativescript-camera”: “0.0.8”,
“nativescript-na-camera”: “^1.2.0”,
“nativescript-theme-core”: “~1.0.4”,
“reflect-metadata”: “~0.1.8”,
“rxjs”: “~6.1.0”,
“tns-core-modules”: “~4.1.0”,
“zone.js”: “^0.8.26”
},

Comment: Have you tried: 

var camera = require("nativescript-camera"); at the start of your TakePicture func

Answer (score 0):

The `requestPermissions` method is returning a `Promise` which you can use to verify that the permissions are given.

```
Camera.requestPermissions().then(() => {
   // you can take photos now
}).catch(() => {
   // user denied permissions
})
```